# MongoDB TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: mongodb, docker, typeerror

I am running this app on docker and whenever I hit localhost:3000/createMongo or localhost:3000/readMongo I encounter this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at /app/index.js:24:25
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at expressInit (/app/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

it seems like MongoDB has been updates and something about the syntax in my code is not being read properly.

side note: whenever I hit localhost:3000, the page is rendered successfully I see the message "Connected correctly to the server!!.

Here's my index.js file:

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// the name "mongo" comes from the docker link, in the docker-compose.yml
var url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/dockerdemo';
var db;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, database) {
    if(err){ console.log('failed to connect: ' + err); return;}
    db = database;
    console.log("Connected correctly to server!!");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Greetings from the server!!');
});

app.get('/createMongo', function(req, res){ 

    var name = 'user' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    var email = name + '@mit.edu';

    var collection = db.collection('customers');
    var doc = {'name':name, 'email':email};
    collection.insert(doc, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        res.send(result);
    });      
});


app.get('/readMongo', function(req, res){  

    var results = null;    
    var collection = db
        .collection('customers')
        .find()
        .toArray(function(err, docs) {
            console.dir(docs);
            res.send(docs);
    });
});



app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Which `console.log()` message from the connection call are you getting?

Comment: This: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)